# How to make a div to expand to its parent

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am being struggling a lot with this but at the moment with no avail.

I have the following structure:-

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  border: solid 1px red;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #eee;
}

#contenedor {
  width: 1173px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: url('/Images/separador.png') repeat-y right top;
}

#lateral {
  width: 180px;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  background-image: url(/Images/Falabella/fondomenu.png);
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
}

#contenido {
  float: left;
  width: 990px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor" style="display: table;">
  <div id="lateral">
  </div>
  <div id="contenido">
  </div>
</div>
```

The "lateral" DIV contains static content. The "contenido" DIV contains some static content and a jqgrid which is populated using AJAX, so,the height is dynamic.

Well.. after all page is loaded, "contenido" DIV is correctly expanded to fit all children heights, The problem is that "lateral" DIV remains the the same height when the page was loaded. It does not make equal the height to "contenido" DIV.

How can I solve this?

I have seen that the HTML and BODY does not expand vertically either, however, "contenedor" DIV and "contenido" DIV do.

Comment: add `display: flex` to `contenedor` if a `flexbox` is an option...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already using `display: table` in the container element, you can just use `display: table-cell` on `#lateral`  and `#contenido` plus erase the floats, the absolute position and other unnessessary parameters (see code below - I also inserted some blindtext content).

```css
html, body {
        border: solid 1px red;
        height: 100%
        overflow: visible;
    }
    
    body {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     background-color: #eee;
    }
    
    #contenedor {
     width: 1173px;
     height: 100%;
     background-color: #fff;
     background: url('/Images/separador.png') repeat-y right top;
    }
    #contenedor > div {
        display: table-cell;
      }
    #lateral {
     width: 180px;
     background-image: url(/Images/Falabella/fondomenu.png);
     background-repeat: repeat-y;
    }
    
    #contenido {
     width: 990px;
     background-color: #fff;
        padding-bottom: 30px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="contenedor" style="display: table;">
      <div id="lateral">
      </div>
      <div id="contenido">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</p>
        <p>Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus.</p>
        <p>Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui.</p>
        <p>Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante.</p>
        <p>Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero. Fusce vulputate eleifend sapien. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.</p>
        <p>Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante.</p>
        <p>Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero. Fusce vulputate eleifend sapien. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.</p>
        <p>Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante.</p>
        <p>Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero. Fusce vulputate eleifend sapien. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.</p>
        <p>Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Cras ultricies mi eu turpis hendrerit fringilla. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In ac dui quis mi consectetuer lacinia. Nam pretium turpis et arcu. Duis arcu tortor, suscipit eget, imperdiet nec, imperdiet iaculis, ipsum. Sed aliquam ultrices mauris. Integer ante arcu, accumsan a, consectetuer eget, posuere ut, mauris. Praesent adipiscing. Phasellus ullamcorper ipsum rutrum nunc. Nunc nonummy metus. Vestibulum volutpat pretium libero. Cras id dui. Aenean ut</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This worked, however, the shadowed right border (that was achieved with "background: url('/Images/separador.png') repeat-y right top;") disappeared. How can I get it back?

Comment: Finally, I didn't know why the background dixappeared, but I have replaced that shadowed border by the normal border using CSS border-right.

Answer (score 0):

Following your approach (*using `display:table` on the container*) you could set the `#lateral` and `#contenido` to `display:table-cell` and it would get fixed;

```
#contenedor{display:table}
#contenedor > *{display:table-cell;}
```

---

A more modern approach would be to use [flexible boxes (*flexbox*)<sup>mdn</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).

```css
html, body {
        height: 100%;
        border: solid 1px red;
    }
    
    body {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     background-color: #eee;
    }
    *{box-sizing:border-box;}
    #contenedor {
     width: 1173px;
     height: 100%;
        display:flex;
        flex-direction:row;
     background-color: #fff;
     background: url('/Images/separador.png') repeat-y right top;
    }
    
    #lateral {
     flex:0 0 180px;
     background-image: url(/Images/Falabella/fondomenu.png);
     background-repeat: repeat-y;
    }
    
    #contenido {
        flex:1;
     background-color: #fff;
        padding-bottom: 30px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">
      <div id="lateral">lateral</div>
      <div id="contenido">contenido</div>
    </div>
```